# How to alter local tasks (aka tabs)

Tags: 8, webforms

I am following the info [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-alter-local-tasks-aka-tabs) to alter 'Results' page for my webform. I want to do exactly what is given in the example on that page (make the table view the default, remove the 'Submissions' tab.

I have copied the code listed into my webform.module file, cleared cache, restarted MAMP (running locally), however the changes aren't reflected on my site.

Here is the code snippet:

```
 * Implements hook_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function webform_ui_local_tasks_alter(&$local_tasks) {
  // Change 'Results' route to display the results 'Table'.
  $local_tasks['entity.webform.results']['route_name'] = 'entity.webform.results_table';
  // Move the 'Table' sub task to be first.
  $local_tasks['entity.webform.results_table']['weight'] = -100;
  // OPTIONAL: Remove the 'Submissions' task.
  unset($local_tasks['entity.webform.results_submissions']);

  // Apply the same changes the Webform node local tasks.
  if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('webform_node')) {
    $local_tasks['entity.node.webform.results']['route_name'] = 'entity.node.webform.results_table';
    $local_tasks['entity.node.webform.results_table']['weight'] = -100;
    unset($local_tasks['entity.node.webform.results_submissions']);
  }
}
```

The code example in the snippet above uses:

`function webform_ui_local_tasks_alter(&$local_tasks)`

which I assume is different from:

`function webform_local_tasks_alter(&$local_tasks)`

which is already present in the webform.module file. Therefore I have placed the snippet on its own within the file. I have also tried adding the individual functions in the snippet to the `function webform_local_tasks_alter(&$local_tasks)` section already present in webform.module.

Any suggestions for that I need to do differently?

Comment: `I have copied the code listed into my webform.module file` You shouldn't hack the Webform module (or any core or contrib module) directly. Guess what's going to happen when you update the module down the road? You will lose your changes!

Comment: The proper way is to create your own custom module and add a `hook_local_tasks_alter()` there. You will need to make sure your [module has higher weight](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186506/how-to-reduce-increase-modules-weight-on-the-module-install-process) so it runs after the webform's alter hook.

Comment: I see why your bad practice approach isn't working. Code suppose to go inside **/webform/modules/weform_ui.module** not in /webform/weform.module. Remember, hook gets replaced by module's machine name, but like I said create your own custom module.