# How do I hide "View most recent blog entries"

Tags: 8

If you enable the contributed [**Blog**](https://www.drupal.org/project/blog) module, a link with the anchor text "View most recent blog entries" shows up on every post.  I want to hide this link using PHP (i.e. not resorting to css or javascript).

So far I've tried this in `hook_node_links_alter()`:

```
unset($links['usernames_blog']['#links']['blog_usernames_blog']);
```

It doesn't work. I don't think the offending link is in the links array, but somewhere else (I've yet to figure out where).

Comment: I've never attempted to enable the Blog module so I'm just taking a guess here but does the view your want to disable show up in the View menu (structure->views)? If so you should easily be able to disable it with the buttons on the far right.

Comment: Is there any reason to use the Blog module at all? Seems to me its sole purpose is to make migration from earlier versions easier.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong It may be that I would be better off without it. I am migrating a Drupal 7 multi-user blog to Drupal 8, and it seemed a good idea at the time to continue using the **Blog** module. I'll explore alternative approaches if I am unable to get rid of this misfeature.

Comment: @mrlexington I do not want to disable a view. I want to hide a link that shows up on every node on the site (whether the user who authored the node actually has a blog or not)

Comment: Enable Devel's submodule Kint and then `ksm($variables);` inside the hook in question, flush cache and then check what's in that array. Maybe you need to ensure your implementation runs last via `hook_implements_alter`, but that's just a wild guess. Same as you I would need to look into the Blog module's code to find out how the links got added in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `unset($links['usernames_blog']['#links']['blog_usernames_blog']);`

Might be correct, but make sure your module has higher weight, so your hook alter fires after the blog's module.

I suggest using the [weight module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186506/how-to-reduce-increase-modules-weight-on-the-module-install-process) to give your custom module higher weight. Else, you could run on [Devel's](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) Execute PHP `module_set_weight('mymodule', 11);` to give it higher weight.

---

If that doesn't work, If you look at the module's code, there is another link that gets added [via hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/blog/blob/8.x-2.x/blog.module#L13)

Thus, all you gotta do is use [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter/8.2.x)

**mymodule.module**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter().
 */
function mymodule_user_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  if (!empty($build['summary']['blog'])) {
    unset($build['summary']['blog']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Using `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter()` to `unset($build['summary']['blog']);`is the correct solution.