# How do I override an exposed filter input type?

Tags: 8, views

I'm writing a module to change input HTML attributes with the next code:

```php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custom_numeric_filter_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $field = 'yourfieldname';
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && array_key_exists($field, $form)) {
    $form[$field]['#type'] = "range";
    $form[$field]['#step'] = 5;
    $form[$field]['#size'] = 5;
    $form[$field]['#min'] = 10;
    $form[$field]['#max'] = 60;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the type gets overwritten back to `number` by something else.

<s>I have Better Exposed Filters installed, maybe it gets rewritten there but why? And how can I make sure my module code has priority?</s> With the help from [NoSssweat](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/27710/no-sssweat) I made sure it was executed after BEF and it didn't help.

Comment: `How can I make sure my module code has priority?` By giving your module higher weight so your hook executes last. You can achieve that [like this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/186517/27710) or [with this](https://www.drupal.org/project/modules_weight)

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks, is there a way to see all these weights for installed modules?

Comment: yes, [with this](https://www.drupal.org/project/modules_weight).

Comment: It was after BEF but I still changed the weight, cleared the cache and it didn't help unfortunately. Maybe it's something else. Like `range` being an unknown value for some reason.

Comment: Try setting type to `BETWEEN`, just a guess.

Comment: `$form[$field]['#type'] = "BETWEEN";`? `Undefined index: yourfieldname in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\FilterPluginBase->acceptExposedInput() (line 1446 of core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/filter/FilterPluginBase.php).`

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```
function seven_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (in_array($form_id, ['node_page_form', 'node_page_edit_form'])) {
    $form['field_number']['widget'][0]['value']['#type'] = 'range';
  }
}
```

I think this post will help you, check once - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2958499#comment-12558959

Comment: `Undefined index: widget` error, sadly

Comment: This didn't solve the problem but the link is useful, thank you.

Comment: Okay, that's great that link was helpful to you,  what you changed in your alter code ? After that error ?

Comment: Not yet, I've just reverted it to a previous state for now.